# TextView showing "?" mark instead of text using STM32 TouchGFX?

Tags: stm32, touchgfx

I want to fill a textView with a string, after a click on a button.
I did every thing correctly but it shows only the "a" character and the other with a fallback character.
this is the function that fill the text view buffer
[image]

The wildcard

[image]

The topography

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Unicode::strncpy()` instead of `snprintf()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Unicode::strncpy(textArea1Buffer1, x, TEXTAREA1BUFFER1_SIZE);
Unicode::snprintf(textArea1Buffer1, TEXTAREA1BUFFER1_SIZE, "%s", textArea1Buffer1);
```